# Robot swarm, Maximum area coverage

Tags: computational-geometry, voronoi-diagrams, robotics

I have a swarm of`N` robots to place on a plane area. Each robot would control a sub part of the area (navigating in it). What algorithm could I use to deploy my robots so that they all control a comparable part of the area.

I was looking at Voronoi diagrams but I cannot find how to determine the location of the points.

Sorry if this is not very clear, I am not even sure what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "comparable part of the area" you mean that they should all scan a region of equal area. Additionally, knowing what kind of plane area you have would be helpful, is it convex, is it concave, is it just a regular polygon? If you know this then there are easier ways to do it.
So assuming you want for the worst case, a concave polygon, the best solution that I know of is [this](http://www.khetarpal.org/polygon-splitting/).
This page has a detailed explanation of the algorithm and there's even some comments with implementations.

Comment: I am working on regular polygons at the moment, but could evolve into something more complex later. Thank you for your link, I am going to take a look at it.

Comment: If you are working with regular polygons for now the solution is much simpler noticing that a regular polygon is just N triangles with same area around the center. Good luck.